# Java 2D Array learn

Tags: java

I have this practice Java code that I'm trying to finish.
The obvious problem is that when I try to print the `array[1][2]`, it returns null, so I'm thinking the array might be empty. How do I take the user input to put in the array?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Studyone {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int row = 13;
        int col = 25;
        String sentence;
        String sentence2;
        String [][] map = new String[row][col];
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0;i < map.length; i++) 
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the element");
                sentence2 = input.nextLine();
                map[i][j]=sentence2;
                if (row>col)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(map[1][2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help, i think:

```
for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0;j < map[i].length; j++) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the element");
        sentence2 = input.nextLine();
        map[i][j]=sentence2;
     }
}
```

Comment: i tried it but the code input just keeps going non-stop

Comment: please check your second loop. Do you really use j instead of i?

Comment: Yes i checked it, it seems work correctly now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
for (int j = 0;i < map.length; i++)
```

to

```
for (int j = 0;j < map[0].length; j++)
```

**For example**, suppose `x = new int[3][4]`, `x[0]`, `x[1]`, and `x[2]` are one-dimensional
arrays and each contains four elements, as shown in the figure `x.length` is `3`, and
`x[0].length`, `x[1].length`, and `x[2].length` are `4`

[image]

Comment: Fancy pic. I like it. I'd like it even more if arrays `x[0]`, `x[1]` and `x[2]` had different lengths, but it's cool already.

Comment: @KrzysztofJabłoński are you asking about jagged array?

Comment: That's how they're called... Not really asking for another pic, though it's worth emphasizing that inner arrays can have different lengths.

Comment: @KrzysztofJabłoński what you want is a **jagged array** you can look for it on the google

Answer (score 1):

- You are incrementing and checking condition for `i` instead of `j` in inner loop.
- Use `map[i].length` condition for inner loop

So your inner loop should be

```
for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++)
                ^1      ^2         ^3
```

As first will increment `i` twice and for `col` you have to consider array of one dimension but you are considering `map` which may lead to `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Here `map[i][j]=sentence2;` `j` will remain zero

> I changed it, but the input just keeps going on and on non-stop.

It will as you have 13 rows and 25 columns so it will take time to insert all the values.So, just change(reduce) size of array and try.

Comment: i changed it, but the input just keeps going on and on non-stop.
@TAsk

Answer (score 1):

change

```
for (int j = 0;i < map.length; i++)
```

to

```
for (int j = 0;j < map[i].length; j++)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `j < map[i].length` in the second line and `int i = 0` in the first?

Answer (score 0):

Amend your code to the following:

```
for (int j = 0;i < map.length; i++)
```

to

```
for (int j = 0;i < map[j].length; j++)
```

Comment: here i < map[i].length needs to be j < map[i].length